# Sending a POST request with JSON data in Linux

Tags: linux, bash, api, ssl, curl

I first work with `Postman` to test an `api` to do simple `POST` requests and everything worked fine as it is easy to add values in the body part.

Now I need to do the same from a Linux console. I tried using the `curl` command.

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d'{"DeviceId":"L","TransactionValue":"360","RSSI":"360","Time":"2018-07-30T11:02:00"}' https://IPADDRESS.com.au
```

And other commands based on the curl but everytime I have this `error log` displayed on my Linux console :

```
(35) ssl_handshake returned - PolarSSL: (-0x7780) SSL - A fatal alert message was received from our peer
```

I don't understand why I have an issue on the Linux console and not on Postman and what is this issue.

Many thanks in advance.
Cheers!!

Comment: instead of `https://IPADDRESS.com.au` are you using an actual https url and you are just masking that from us?  The "peer" error tells me it is something with SSL, some googling shows it has to do with the ssl version/ciphers used

Comment: @ivanivan: Me, the "SSL" at the start of the error tells me it is something with SSL :D

Comment: @Amadan SSL on the server side, sry

Comment: @ivanivan Yes indeed I use an actual https url I'm just hiding the real url. I don't have access on the server side. Do you think there is nothing I can do ?

Comment: It seems to involve what SSL library your cURL was compiled against.  What version of cURL in what release of what distro on what hardware?

Comment: The question isn't just "is there 'https' in the URL", it's do you actually use a valid host name, not just the server's IP address?

Comment: @ivanivan I am using a LoRa gateway, the model is a dragino LG0-S. Here the details of the hardware : Dragino HE Linux Module
CPU 400M Mips CPU
DDR: 64MB
flash:16MB

I don't know how to provide other informations sorry.

Comment: @tripleee I double checked the url and I'm sure about it. I use this same url on Postman and it works so I guess it's the server IP address ?

Comment: What exactly does your Postman test look like?

Comment: @tripleee I choose POST in a spinner menu, then enter the URL and in the body I write some JSON values, as following : 
   
   {
               "DeviceId" : "C",
               "TransactionValue" : 192.49,
               "RSSI": 240.40,
               "Time" : "2018-05-04 20:36:06.000"
     }

Comment: The same URL as you use for `curl`? No `Host:` header or other shenanigans?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem is almost certainly with the backend ssl library, in your case, PolarSSL/mbedTLS, it seems your version is from 2014 or older.

which version of PolarSSL are you using? you can find out by running `curl --version` , what does it output?

try updating to the latest version of MbedTLS and re-compile curl, and try again, you can find the latest version here: https://tls.mbed.org/tech-updates/releases

(btw, seems PolarSSL and mbedTLS refers to the same thing, they just changed the name back in 2015. the fact that the error message refers to it as PolarSSL implies that you're using an old version **from 2014 or or older**)

Comment: Yes indeed it seems my curl version is old. Here the output of 'curl --version' : 'curl 7.40.0 (mips-openwrt-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.40.0 PolarSSL/1.3.14
Protocols: file ftp ftps http https
Features: IPv6 Largefile SSL'

I am going to try to update it with the link you gave me. Thank you!

Comment: I finally was able to update the latest version of MbedTLS. Now my curl works. Thank you for your help mate!

Answer (score 0):

Your command is right, the problem could be that you have an outdated curl / PolarSSL version since it seems to be working with postman.

Here is an example using `curl 7.61.0` posting to httpbin.org:

```
$ curl -X POST https://httpbin.org/post -H "Content-type: application/json" -d '{"DeviceId":"L","TransactionValue":"360","RSSI":"360","Time":"2018-07-30T11:02:00"}'
{
  "args": {},
  "data": "{\"DeviceId\":\"L\",\"TransactionValue\":\"360\",\"RSSI\":\"360\",\"Time\":\"2018-07-30T11:02:00\"}",
  "files": {},
  "form": {},
  "headers": {
    "Accept": "*/*",
    "Connection": "close",
    "Content-Length": "83",
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
    "Host": "httpbin.org",
    "User-Agent": "curl/7.43.0"
  },
  "json": {
    "DeviceId": "L",
    "RSSI": "360",
    "Time": "2018-07-30T11:02:00",
    "TransactionValue": "360"
  },
  "origin": "178.197.231.122",
  "url": "https://httpbin.org/post"
}
```

If the previous example works, then try setting the host, for example:

```
$ curl -X POST https://IPADDRESS.com.au \
-H "Host: httpbin.org" \
-H "Content-type: application/json" \
-d '{"DeviceId":"L","TransactionValue":"360","RSSI":"360","Time":"2018-07-30T11:02:00"}'
```

Notice the `-H "Host: httpbin.org"` replace it with your own domain.

Comment: his libcurl is compiled with PolarSSL/mbedTLS, a competitor to OpenSSL. OpenSSL is not involved here. curl supports [multiple SSL backend libraries](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/ssl-compared.html), and which one curl use is chosen at compile-time.